# How to connect sqlite with an online  database on Phonegap

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, cordova

I made a database using phonegap[cordova 1.7.0] sqlite on IOS5. 
But I now want to switch this database with one that I already have on an online server. 
Is there some method to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you attempting to replace the contents of the local database with the one on the server?  Or are you now looking to stop using the local database and always use one on a remote server instead?  And is the database global data - read only for all clients, or does it store per-user data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to use your current logic for handling database access to connect to remote sqlite database.

I think such use case is not possible out of the box. Cordova is using support for WebSQL built into iOS and Android (or provides own compatible implementation).

There are at least 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Create service which allows access to your remote database, and then create client side sync service which synchronizes that on the client and server. This way you will have full offline support plus data will be backed up on the server.
2. Write your own Cordova plugin which allows access to remote sqlite databases but uses WebSQL interface. I guess you could reuse most of the current logic from iOS WebSQL implementation, but instead of accessing local sqlite file on the device, use the database on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Write a server side application that provides access to the database.

Answer (score 2):

There's an sqlite plugin for Phonegap. If the online sqlite is (semi-)publicly available/downloadable, you could have the Phonegap download the db file (there's a Download plugin, I think), and have your customized sqlite plugin use this db.

Comment: Good idea. The only drawback of that plugin is that it's only for iOS and has a little bit different api. [Phonegap-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin)

Comment: There are versions for iOS and Android, and I think (at least the Android version does) try to stick to the WebSQL/Phonegap API. But yeah it could be a liiiiiiiittle bit more work... (It's always a little more work when others have to do it right?)

Answer (score 1):

Either you can also do it in this way. Create a XML file dbase on server and parse it then you can make changes to your existing database by reading the xml files contents.

Comment: But where is the phone gap usage ?

Comment: well can you give more details coz what you exactly want to achieve is not clear to us plz give more details as mentioned by ryan in his comment. well if the database structure is gonna be the same then you can use the xml thing tht i mentioned, check for the new records or even refresh entire dbase if you wish to. well you can achieve your goal this way also.